# NSWindow tracking

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I would like to track each time a certain window appears (becomes visible to the user) in a OS X app. Where would be the most adequate place to call the tracker?

[windowWillLoad](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindowController/windowWillLoad), maybe?

I expected to find something like `windowWillAppear` but it seems I'm thinking too much iOS.

Comment: What do you mean by "shown"? How is the window coming into view and going out of view -- hiding, closing, loading, makeKey, makeMain? There are quite a few choices, and which ones are used would affect the answer to this question.

Comment: For tracking purposes, I would define "shown" as "becomes visible to the user". makeMain is not a choice as not all windows can be main.

Answer (score 1):

How about getting notification such as `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification`, By main I guess the one which is top most on screen directly visible by user.

see : [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html)

Comment: `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification` is not called for panels, who are also windows. Will try with `NSWindowDidBecomeKeyNotification`...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, one would expect that a window would notify its delegate or its controller with a `windowWillAppear` or `windowDidAppear` message, or post a documented notification like `NSWindowDidAppearNotification`. But alas, none of those exist. I filed a bug report with Apple and was given the advice to use a storyboard and a view controller instead. This is unhelpful in legacy apps that already use a bunch of window controllers and xibs.

You could subclass `NSWindow` and override `orderWindow:relativeTo:` to send a notification. Most, but not quite all, of the messages that make a window show itself ultimately go through this method, including `orderBack:`, `orderFront:`, `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, and `-[NSWindowController showWindow:]`. But `orderFrontRegardless` does *not* go through `orderWindow:relativeTo:`, so you would also want to override that for completeness.

Another way to be notified is to make a subclass of `NSViewController` that controls some view that's always visible in the window. The view controller will receive `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.

If you're subclassing `NSWindow` or `NSViewController` already for some other reason, either of these is a reasonable solution.

If you're not subclassing `NSWindow` already, and don't have an `NSViewController` subclass for a view that's always visible in the window, then another way is to use Cocoa bindings to connect the window's `visible` binding to a property one of your objects. For example, I have a custom `NSWindowController` subclass. I gave it a `windowIsVisible` property:

```
@interface MyWindowController ()

@property (nonatomic) BOOL windowIsVisible;

@end
```

and I implemented the accessors like this:

```
- (BOOL)windowIsVisible { return self.window.visible; }

- (void)setWindowIsVisible:(BOOL)windowIsVisible {
    NSLog(@"window %@ became %s", self.window, windowIsVisible ? "visible" : "hidden");
}
```

and in `awakeFromNib`, I bind the window's `visible` binding to the property like this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self.window bind:NSVisibleBinding toObject:self withKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(windowIsVisible)) options:nil];
}
```

When the window becomes visible, the `setWindowIsVisible:` setter is called with an argument of `YES`. Note that if the whole app is hidden and reappears, the setter is called again, even though it wasn't called with argument `NO` when the app was hidden. So be careful not to assume the window was previously hidden.

Also, the binding might create a retain cycle, so you should probably unbind it when the window is closed, unless you want to keep the window and controller around. Note that the window does post `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` when it's closing, so you don't need any special magic to detect that.